# In Dark Souls, does Havel's set lose durability, and, if yes, can it be repaired?

Tags: dark-souls

I've noticed that the description for Havel's set items mention that they are carved from stone. Stone and crystal items can't be repaired once they lose durability, however they are highly resilient to make up for that. I noticed that Havel's armor has 900 durablity, however that durability has not gone down.

Are there certain conditions for it to lose durability, i.e. certain attacks (like Quelaag's lava spewing attack), or is it just that the armor is so resilient I have yet to notice even 1 point drop in durability? If it does lose durability, can the armor be repaired?

Havel's set is unique and arguably one of the best, if not the best, armor in the game (given high enough stamina to use effectively). The only caveat I could think of is the possibility that it has a finite lifetime.

Comment: pretty sure it can be repaired if it loses durability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havel's set does lose durability and can be repaired, however it cannot be upgraded.

Comment: Yeah, after playing for an entire day I noticed that it went down by a couple durability points and that I was able to repair it. Even without upgrades, that armor set is really over powered. Only downside is the immense weight, which at higher soul levels can be negated with the help of endurance.